# jQuery UI replaceWith() animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

So I have a div:

```
<div id="lol">
Some random text!
</div>
```

And I have other div:

```
<div id="happy">
lol
</div>
```

How could a make an animation, in which the first div is smoothly replaced by the second one? If a Do a fadeIn/fadeOut, the second div would only starting to happear after the first div was gone.

Comment: To do this they will both have to be visible at the same time, and to make two elements sit in the same position at the same time, they would need to be positioned absolutely. At that point you could just fadeToggle them both. the hidden will show and the shown will hide.

Answer (score 2):

I think simply this would work.

```
$("#happy").hide();

$("#smooth").click(function(){

    $("#happy").show();//no transition for this
    $("#lol").slideUp();//with transition


});
```

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPkQC/)

or you can even toggle the effect like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qPkQC/1/)

Comment: Please read my question, that is not smooth, the first element first disappears and then the second one shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Quite easy. Assuming #lol is visible and #happy is not. (You can use jQuery's show/hide to set that up).

```
$('#lol').fadeOut(function() {
  $('#happy').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#lol").fadeOut(1000,function(){

$("#happy").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This still requires one to completely fade out before the 2nd fades in, which was clearly something he wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what do you want:

```
$("button").click(function () {
$(".happy").toggle('slow');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/igorpollo/8GQv7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to both of these divs, then toggle the class. This will allow both to toggle simultaneously (one fades in at the same time the other is fading out).

HTML

```
<div id="lol" class="toggle">
Some random text!
</div>
<div id="happy" class="toggle">
lol
</div>
<button id="btn">Replace</button>
```

JQuery

```
$("#happy").hide();

$("#btn").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggle(2000);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5ZkH/)

Answer (score 0):

Using fadeOut/fadeIn will work if you use absolute positioning.  There are many other options as well.

I'm not at all sure what you would like to see in your final result, but here are a few examples:

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/kqQ6F/4/)

CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
div.container div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="lol">Some random text!</div>
    <div id="happy" style="display: none">lol</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="lol1">Some random text!</div>
    <div id="happy1" style="display: none">lol</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="lol2">Some random text!</div>
    <div id="happy2" style="left: -200px">lol</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="lol3">Some random text!</div>
    <div id="happy3" style="left: 200px; opacity: 0;">lol</div>
</div>
```

Sample code:

```
$('#lol').fadeOut(1000);
$('#happy').fadeIn(1000);


$('#lol1').slideUp(1000);
$('#happy1').slideDown(1000);

$('#lol2').animate({left: -200});
$('#happy2').animate({left: 0});


$('#lol3').animate({left: -200}, 1000);
$('#happy3').animate({left: 0, opacity: 1}, 1500);
```